# Unable to setup magento

Tags: magento2

I am trying to setup magento 2 on ubuntu 14.04.

But when it reaches the database setup it gives me an error

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Framework\Stdlib\String, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils given, called in
>   /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php
>   on line 74 and defined in
>   /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
>   on line 194

I have searched everywhere but unable to find the answer.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the real solution, but did you already try to install it via command line? Maybe this will skip the error. You can modify this script, but this is the one from the Magento docs:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html for more information.

Comment: Already tried, no use :(

Answer (score 1):

I have already setup magento 2 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS version,

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=test@test.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago
```

You have to create database before install. in above i have create database magento2. you can keep your custom name for db.

Comment: Yes I already tried using CLI but it gives me more such errors. i.e, wrong arguments passed

Comment: And also created a database before setup.

Comment: Have you checked your db name root and password is root? in above command i have set db name and password is root. This is user and passwrod for mysql. If you have different  username and password then you have to set as per your settings in above --db-user and --db-password field.

Comment: Yes I did that I had replaced it with mysql credentials. Using which I login to mysql workbench.

Comment: its working or not now? if working then accept this answer for help to community user.